# Licensing for forked projects

Tags: licensing, forking

If a project is licensed with MIT license, can someone fork the project, create significant changes, and put a more restrictive license on it? Or even copyright it?

Answer (score 7):

So we suppose that Alice creates a piece of code *ab initio* and publishes it under the X11 licence (the [more precise name](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/license-list.html#X11License) of what is often referred to as "*the MIT licence*").  Bob then copies it and makes significant changes (resulting in *the new work*).

> Can Bob copyright it?

The new work is a piece of code in which *two* people, Bob and Alice, have a copyright interest.  That's not something either of them has to do, it flows out of their authorship and the [Berne Convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berne_Convention).  No third party may then do with the new work those things which are restricted by copyright without the consent of both Alice and Bob; Alice and Bob may each do only those things with the consent of Bob and Alice, respectively.

By publishing under a non-[copyleft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copyleft) free licence, Alice has permitted a very wide range of things to be done.

> Can Bob put a more restrictive licence on it?

As I have written [elsewhere](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/4149/can-one-take-bsd-licensed-code-and-distribute-it-under-gpl/4194#4194), yes, he may.  Some free software licences forbid distribution under terms more restrictive than their own (eg GPLv3 ss 5c, 7); the X11 licence is not one of these.  Bob may therefore distribute the new work under the requirements of **both** the X11 licence **and** (eg) GPLv3.  Note that this isn't dual-licensing, where the recipient chooses which of two licences (s)he wishes to apply; the requirements of **both** licences apply.  GPLv3 permits this since the demands of the X11 licence do not conflict with those of GPLv3 (ie, X11 is "compatible" with GPLv3); X11 permits it since it does not forbid adding additional restrictions.

Bob may even distribute the new work under almost-completely-restrictive terms, as proprietary software, so long as he fulfils the (very lightweight) labelling requirements of the X11 licence.

Comment: This is so helpful.  Thank you!

Comment: @JessicaWilkinson thank you for those kind words, and you're very welcome! Feel free to accept the answer if you're fully satisfied with it.